# HTML Attributes to JSON

Tags: jquery, html, json, diagram

I've been developing a diagramming tool/editor. The data that I need to store is in the HTML attributes. Is there a way to get this data?

[image: This is the screenshot of what I am telling]

Also, I need the diagram to be converted to JSON

```
function createJSON(){
    var data = new Object();
    $("input[class = process]").each(function() {
        data[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
        jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);
    });
```

This works but I need the html attributes to be converted into json too.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain exactly what you want to do, more specifically? Like, what sort of data are you hoping to store and retrieve?

Comment: I need to get the attributes in the NamedNodeMap like using getnameditem, i need these attributes to be converted to JSON.

Comment: can you share a sample of the json you are looking for

Comment: {
            "title":"Process title",
            "owner":"key",
            "desc":"text description",
            "root":{
                "title":"Root title",
                "subprocess":"Start",
                "msg":"Sample start",
                "permissions":[],
                "children":[
                    {
                        "title":"Decision Node",
                        "subprocess":"Decision",
                        "msg":"Is it a holiday?",

Comment: I think you're going to need type of element, size of element, position of one corner of the element, then specific attributes regarding details of the elements, right?

Comment: Actually, it is all in the attributes like style = position then class = type... but I can't find a way to get this data...

Comment: @jihyo btw, `new Object()` is not idiomatic #cargocult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the `attributes` property:

```
var data = {};

$("input[class=process]").each(function () {
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    data[name] = {};
    $.each(this.attributes, function (i, attr) {
        if (attr.specified) {
            data[name][attr.name] = attr.value;
        }
    });
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Then to restore it, you can do something like this:

```
$("input[class=process]").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        name  = $this.attr("name");
    if (typeof data[name] === "undefined") {
        return;
    }
    $.each(data[name], function (name, value) {
        $this.attr(name, value);
    });
});
```

Comment: It still doesn't get the needed attributes. It only shows the class = process.. i need the attributes of the diagram which can be seen in the div.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nxsjgqx6/ It grabs all the specified attributes on the selected input elements.